# I set the proxy for yum in Linux CentOS and it gives me error when I try to download

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I installed Linux CentOS on VMWare Workstation, I am behind a proxy, I modified the yum.conf file and addres the proxy port user and password and when I try yum install xxx it gives me this message : Could not retrieve mirrorlist etc. and the second line of the error is : 14:curl#5 - "Could not resolve proxy: proxy.my.proxyname; Unknown error"

How can I solve this issue ? What might be the problem ?

Comment: Can you ping the proxy in shell prompt (`ping proxy.my.proxyname`)?

Comment: It says name or service unknown

Comment: I forgot to mention the Linux is installed in a virtual machina VMWare

Comment: So, you have a general DNS problem, not a yum problem. A possible quick fix is to add the proxy to your /etc/hosts but this would likely only solve part of the problem. Debugging DNS problem isn't new. This has very likely been already asked.

Comment: And how should I search I`m a newbie only working as a programmer for 6 months and it`s my first linux task and i dont know what to seartch

Comment: Make a new question "DNS problem in CentOS under VMware" here. State VMware version, guest OS type and version, `dig proxy.my.proxyname` output (if `dig` is already installed, otherwise try `nslookup` instead). Tag you question DNS, CentOS, VMware. Not all systems resolve names the same way, and I have no RHEL/CentOS at hand to try things. While entering the question, SE may point your to similar questions that will be the start of an answer.